# Error Linking FFTW in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fftw

I am using the FFTW library in VC++ and trying to run this code. When I run it, I get the following error

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libfftw3l-3.dll'

I made the dll and lib files from as indicated on the FFTW website and added the dll files to my project with *Linker > Input > Additional Dep*.

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan p;
    int nx = 5;
    int ny = 5;
    int i;
    float M_PI = 3.14;

    /* Allocate the input and output arrays, and create the plan */
    in = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * nx * ny);
    out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * nx * ny);
    p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(nx, ny, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD,
FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    /* Now fill the input array with the input data */
    /* We'll simply make a sine wave */
    for (i = 0; i < (nx * ny); i++) {
        in[i][0] = sin(i / 10.0 * M_PI);    /* Real part */
        in[i][1] = 0.0;                          /* Imaginary part */
    }

    /* Actually execute the plan on the input data */
    fftw_execute(p);

    /* Print out the results */
    for (i = 0; i < (nx * ny); i++)
        printf("Coefficient %d: %f%+f*i\n", i, out[i][0], out[i][1]);

    /* Clean up after ourselves */
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(in); fftw_free(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `libfftw3l` is for the `long double` version of FFTW - why is this even in your project ???

Comment: @ Paul: I just followed the instruction in FFTW website, so, you think that I should remove it from linker? Should I add another thing in VC++ directories or somewhere else?

Comment: You need the `libfftw3` DLL, but not the `libfftw3l` or `libfftw3f` DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

The `libfftw3l-3.dll` is for the `long double` version of FFTW. It looks like you do not have this file available on your computer. However, as you don't use any `long double` functions or any single precision `float` functions you only need to link against the `libfftw3-3.dll` library.